# Direct Airside Transit Visa (DATV) for South African

Tags: uk, south-african-citizens, datv

I will be travelling from Switzerland (Geneva) via the UK (Heathrow) to South Africa with British Airways on January 7 2017.

I will be landing and departing from Terminal 5 at Heathrow airport.

I have a valid Swiss living and working permit. My husband is an EU citizen (Portugal). I have a South African passport. My air ticket shows South Africa as my final destination.

On the 29 January 2017, I will fly back to Switzerland via UK (Heathrow) using Terminal 5 for landing and departing once again. I will use my Swiss permit to enter Switzerland.

Do I need Direct Airside Transit visa (DATV)? Will I need to go through immigration/border control at Heathrow? Does landing with British Airways at Heathrow mean I'll stay on the airside and only need to go through security with hand luggage?

Comment: A quick edit, to remove your surname, as it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

If your journey is in a single booking, you will not need to clear immigration. If it's two separate bookings, you will need to clear immigration.

Regardless, however, as a holder of a Swiss residence permit, [you do **not** Need a UK DATV](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/south-africa/transit/somewhere_else/no) to change planes. [If you do clear immigration](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/south-africa/transit/somewhere_else/yes), you must leave (i.e. the next flight must depart) no later than 23:59 the next day.